# Are there any useful tools to analyse an existing Borland Pascal 7.0 App

Tags: pascal, 16-bit, turbo-pascal

We have a body of legacy Apps written in Borland Pascal 7.0 of 16bit, real mode Fame.

Do you know any good tools useful for analyzing such software, such as call graphs, cross-references, IDEs?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have the built exe you could load it in [IDA Pro Disassembler](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) then you get the call graphs and cross references.

If you have the map file, you can start renaming the functions and grok it even better.

That is if you happy to read assembly.

Comment: Thx. We do have the source, I need something to analyze that.

Comment: I assumed you had the source, just offering something better than, write a parser.

Answer (score 2):

If you have source, since most of the TP dialect is still supported by Delphi, you could use Delphi tools. Peganza is the best known vendor of Pascal source analysis tools: http://peganza.com/

Walking through the SIMTEL TurboPas directory might also help to find some minor tools.

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to compile then again using TP7 on a 16bit platform?

In terms of IDEs you could recompile them using Delphi 4,5 or 6 or similar - I don't know about the newer versions of Delphi. You could also recompile them using Free Pascal and the Lazarus IDE. If you are recompiling on something other than TP7 16bit then you will need to consider the 16 to 32 or 64 bit conversion.

Comment: (TP apps still in use are frequently tied to specific hardware and is often not easily ported. To anything)